# Polynomial Modulus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve problem using Fast Fourier transform , in which i have encountered polynomials of following type.

Given polynomials A(x), B(x)

Find another polynomial R(x), such that R(x) = A(x)%B(x).

could some one share reference to algorithm on how to calculate the remainder ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this form? I can't get it.

Comment: @Bernard

edited

Comment: Assuming that the percent sign means "modulo" or "remainder of division", the answer is in the lecture notes by Chandan Saha you refer to in your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512865/inverse-of-a-polynomial-mod as Algorithm 2.